# Totals seems to be wrong

Tags: python

I have the following code, simple I know (please feel free to recommend improvements)

It seems with the shell scripts function, the total seems to be wrong, I count 22 but it is reporting 42, is there a problem with the code.

```
import os

myPath = os.getenv("scripts")
pyCounter = 0 
sqlCounter = 0
shCounter = 0

def python_scripts():
  global pyCounter
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myPath):     
    for file in files:             
      if file.endswith('.py'):             
       pyCounter += 1 

def sql_scripts():
  global sqlCounter
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myPath):     
    for file in files:             
      if file.endswith('.sql'):             
       sqlCounter += 1 

def sh_scripts():
  global shCounter
  shell_ext = ['ksh','sh','bash']
  for shell in shell_ext:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myPath):     
      for file in files:             
        if file.endswith(shell):
           shCounter += 1

python_scripts()
sql_scripts()
sh_scripts()

print ("Python : " + str(pyCounter))
print ("SQL : "  + str(sqlCounter))
print ("Shell : " + str(shCounter))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please indent your could with four spaces and *no* tabs.

Comment: Indentation error in `sh_scripts`: I can't tell which block that last line belongs to, and Python won't be able to either.

Comment: Also, if your problem is with `sh_scripts`, why have you included all the other functions in your code? Don't make us read anything more than we need to.

Comment: Everything that ends with `ksh` or `bash` will also be counted as ending with `sh`.

Comment: If the variable is already declared when you call a function, you can use it directly from inside the function without using `global`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your counts are off because a file name ending in `bash` or `ksh` also ends in `sh`.  You should include a `.` to make sure this is really the extension.  You can also pass a tuple of strings to `str.endswith()`, avoiding one of the loops.

Here's your code cleaned up a bit.  The three functions are basically doing the same thing, just with different extensions, so you should write a single function accepting a parameter.  Instead of using global variables for the counters, simply return the values:

```
def count_files(path, extensions):
    counter = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            counter += file.endswith(extensions)
    return counter

path = os.getenv("scripts")
print count_files(path, '.py')
print count_files(path, '.sql')
print count_files(path, ('.ksh', '.sh', '.bash'))
```

Comment: This is it, that has solved it.  Thank you very much for this.  I though there would be an easier way to write the code, still much to learn.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Use `fnmatch.filter` for this kind of thing, e.g.:

```
import fnmatch
import os

py_files = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(myPath):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.py'):
      py_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

pyCounter = len(py_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to walk your directory tree more than one time.

While you walk it you can keep track of all the extensions you see with a [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Example:

```
import os
from collections import Counter
path = '.'

c = Counter(os.path.splitext(f)[1] for _, _, files in os.walk(path) for f in files)

# now you'll just need to sum or extract the counts that you want
sh_ext = ('.ksh', '.sh', '.bash')
sh_scripts = sum(c[ext] for ext in sh_ext)
py_scripts = c['.py']
```

To take the extension *wim* suggested to use [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), and it's a great advice. Take a look at the doc:

> `os.path.splitext(path)`:
>
> > Split the pathname *path* into a pair `(root, ext)` such that `root + ext == path`, and 
> >     *ext* is empty or begins with a period and contains at most one period. Leading periods on the basename are ignored; `splitext('.cshrc')` returns `('.cshrc', '')`.

Comment: +1 nice solution.  but i would rather use `os.path.splitext` for getting the extension.